# Deploy Node.js application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk from Bitbucket using AWS CodePipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket, aws-codepipeline

I'm writing this post after exhausting all the options I could try.

Scenario:
I want to deploy a lightweight backend logic written in Node.js (using JavaScript, Express.js, MongoDB).

Platforms considered:

- AWS (preferred)
- Heroku
- Bitbucket Pipelines (least preferred)

Currently it's deployed on Heroku (and running as expected), but I want to deploy it on our preferred platform, i.e., AWS. Also, I want the whole deployment process to be automated (using Continuous Delivery/Deployment). 
To achieve that, I created:

- A fresh Node.js environment (v16.0, platform v5.6.0) on Elastic Beanstalk
- A new CodePipeline:

  - Source: Bitbucket
  - Repository ([cloned from here](https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-boilerplate))
  - Change detection options: Start the pipeline on source code change
  - Output artifact format: CodePipeline default
  - Build stage: skipped
  - Deploy provider: AWS Elastic Beanstalk (with correct region, app and env name)

Outcome on every try:

- On the first try when the environment gets created, we get greeted with the default screen:
  [image]
- After subsequent commits, things like this start to show up:
  [image]
- Error pages with error codes in the series of 400s and 500s:
  [image]

To overcome those problems, I scratched all the blog posts and support articles available regarding those issues and followed the steps thoroughly gaining no success in the end.
Some of the (many) solutions I tried:

- Create a [Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-configuration-procfile.html) with the the params
- Write app.js/index.js outside the src/ (dumb thing, I know)
- Switch to immutable deployments (as mentioned [here](https://jg.gg/2020/04/15/debugging-elastic-beanstalk/))

I seriously need help resolving this issue. Any help or guidance towards some solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also faced this quite a long past, I'm sorry I don't recollect the exact fix but it has something to do with the `port` number & with some behind the scenes permissions (even being with admin permissions) try putting the `console.log` around the app bootup in your actual code & then upload to EB. Check the logs in Beanstalk then, it will take you the right route of fix

Comment: @Kgn-web I've tried that too! I placed logs all over the code - in the entry file, routes, controllers, services, and even config files. When trying to pull out logs from EB, this process also fails, because of the following cause: "failed: instance(s) state other than ready".